# Which is better practice for creating one object from another object

Tags: java

In Java, say, I have 2 classes:-

```
class A {
    int a;
    int b;
    String c;
    String d;
}

class B {
    int x;
    int y;
    String e;
    String f;
}
```

Now, say I have an object of class A i.e. aObject and I want to create an object of class B where x corresponds to a, y corresponds to b and so on.

So, there are 2 ways I normally see people to do that :-

```
1. B bObject = new B(aObject.geta(), aObject.getb(), aObject.getc(), aObject.getd());
```

where a constructor is defined in B for all parameters from A.

```
2. B bObject = new B();
bObject.setx(aObject.geta())
bObject.sety(aObject.getb())
bObject.sete(aObject.getc())
bObject.setf(aObject.getd())
```

Where values are given using setter.

Which is the better way to do this? Or there are some scenarios where each of one way makes more sense.

Comment: Most of the cases I would go with the `constructor`. I always prefer having no setters if not needed and just one constructor with all possible fields to avoid `half-backed objects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think the constructor approach is better. Using constructors, you have a chance to make your `B` objects immutable. If you go with setters, you will not be able to do that.

If `A` and `B` are *very* closely related, try making `B`'s constructor accept an `A`:

```
public B(A a) {
    x = a.getA();
    y = a.getB();
    e = a.getC();
    f = a.getD();
}
```

Also, it's pretty rare to create these classes with every property corresponding to another property in another class. If both `A` and `B` are written by you, are you sure you are not doing something wrong? Consider deleting one of the two. If one of them is not written by you, why do you want to create a class that completely copies another class' properties? Have you considered using a wrapper?

Comment: This is needed where we have same attributes in data objects(one fetch from database) and response objects(one returned by API). So, for this case, what should be normally used? I don't think in this case, response object need to be immutable.

Comment: @hatellla In that case, use the constructor with `A` as an argument. I also suggest you to add methods like `ToResponseObject` and `ToDataObject` in `A` and `B`. Then you call the constructors in these methods. This way I think is more readable. And regarding mutability, immutable objects are usually a good practice. Always do it where possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `Constructor` Chaining :

you should use `inheritance` and `super` keyword to refer your class B variable to class A parameters like below code:

```
 class A {
            int a;
            int b;
            String c;
            String d;

            public A(int a, int b, String c, String d) {
                this.a = a;
                this.b = b;
                this.c = c;
                this.d = d;
            }
        }

        class B extends A{
            int x;
            int y;
            String e;
            String f;

            public B(int x, int y, String e, String f) {
                super(x,y,e,f);
//Above line call super class Constructor , Class A constructor .
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.e = e;
                this.f = f;

            }
        }

        A ARefrenceobjB = new B(1,2,"str1","str2");
```

Answer (score -3):

B bObject = new B(aObject.geta(), aObject.getb(), aObject.getc(), aObject.getd()); ,this one will be best practice to create object out of other.